# Disable open into new tab option using google docs viewer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Disable open into new tab option using google docs viewer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That widget is not under script control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add sandbox = "allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation" in the iframe and then the button will not work.